# pdf text extracter class in php

Tags: php, pdf, text-extraction

Is there available any class in php that extract all text from pdf file so i can store it in mysql database. My pdf has many elements like images, tables,plain text,form elements,charts etc.

So far i saw many classes for last two days, that extract texts, but no one facilitate with complete text extraction, Not extracting complete text from pdf.

I want to extract all text from given pdf file, even if the text is in table etc.

Any one know about this ?  :)

Thanks a lot. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the below url,

[Reading the clean text from PDF with PHP](https://webcheatsheet.com/php/reading_clean_text_from_pdf.php)

Comment: Its not extracting complete text, I already try with this one.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this on a linux server, you could try using [apdf2text](http://www.wiredrevolution.com/commands/convert-pdf-file-to-text-with-pdftotext) calling it via [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) then grabing the contents of the output file.

Note that a few pdf to text scripts are around and you'll get different mileage from all.

Comment: how can i use it, i cant understand u ? There is no class in php.

Comment: No it's not a php class, it would need wrapping in a function to pass in a file name and then return the text which you can handle yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested many command line program, but none has 100% result.
So I've started my own library in PHP :

https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser

Currently it's text oriented, but image support will be planned.

If you encountered issues, thanks for sending me your PDF and if possible, the way you made it .